# pandas.IntervalIndex.mid for half open IntervalIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have to deal with Series with an half open interval as index, like this one:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.interval_range(5,50,9, closed='left')
values = [8, 8, 14, 4, 6, 12, 8, 3, 2]

s = pd.Series(values, index)
s
```

*output*:

```
[5, 10)      8
[10, 15)     8
[15, 20)    14
[20, 25)     4
[25, 30)     6
[30, 35)    12
[35, 40)     8
[40, 45)     3
[45, 50)     2
dtype: int64
```

I want to automatically compute the **midpoint** and use it behind the scene for computations.

If I use the `pandas.IntervalIndex.mid` function that, according to the documentation, "*returns the midpoint of each Interval in the IntervalIndex as an Index*" I get:

```
Float64Index([7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 37.5, 42.5, 47.5], dtype='float64')
```

The problem is that my interval is `closed='left'`, so the output I was expecting is:

```
Float64Index([7., 12., 17., 22., 27., 32., 37., 42., 47.], dtype='float64')
```

If the interval was `closed='right'`, I expect:

```
Float64Index([8., 13., 18., 23., 28., 33., 38., 43., 48.], dtype='float64')
```

Is there a way to automatically get the half point for an open or half open interval **without having to specify an offset** for the values returned by `pandas.IntervalIndex.mid`? For the Series used in the example the offset would be -0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an IntervalIndex closed to the left you can use `np.floor` to get the expected index as follows:

```
np.floor(index.mid)
```

Result:

```
Float64Index([7.0, 12.0, 17.0, 22.0, 27.0, 32.0, 37.0, 42.0, 47.0], dtype='float64')
```

---

For a more general solution you can define a method that checks how the intervals are closed:

```
def index_mid(index):
    if index.closed == 'left':
        return np.floor(index.mid)
    elif index.closed == 'right':
        return np.ceil(index.mid)
    else:
        return index.mid
```